# How do you continuously play a note in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Python 2.7

Im trying to create a piano-like thing in pygame where when a key is pressed a note plays. My problem is that I can not figure out how to get the note to play forever while the key is held down. I tried to make a while loop but I couldnt figure out how to leave it.

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 800, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size))

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    break
                elif event.key == pygame.K_i:
                    pygame.mixer.music.load('file.wav') #A
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()

                elif event.key == pygame.K_o:
                    pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').play() #B

                elif event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').play() #C

                elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').play() #D

                elif event.key == pygame.K_t:
                    pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').play() #E

                elif event.key == pygame.K_y:
                    pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').play() #F

                elif event.key == pygame.K_u:
                    pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').play() #G
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while running:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
       pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').stop()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
       pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav').play()
```

While a key is pressed it will continue to play that key but when it isn't pressed anymore it will stop.